# Angular theme start

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have problem with starting Angular theme. I have installed everything on this planet, and that wont work.

When i start gulp serve in cmd , this is response:

```
D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-master\node_modules>gulp serve
[21:07:45] Working directory changed to D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-ad
min-master
[21:07:46] Using gulpfile D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-master\gul
pfile.js
[21:07:46] Starting 'scripts'...
[21:07:46] Starting 'styles'...
[21:07:46] Starting 'stylesAuth'...
[21:07:46] Starting 'styles404'...
[21:07:46] Starting 'copyVendorImages'...
D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-master\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslin
t.js:706
                    throw ex;
                    ^

TypeError: Error while loading rule 'react/display-name': ruleCreator is not a f
unction
    at D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-master\node_modules\eslint\li
b\eslint.js:692:28
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.api.verify (D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\
blur-admin-master\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint.js:671:16)
    at processText (D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-master\node_modu
les\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:230:27)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-mast
er\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:686:26)
    at verify (D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-master\node_modules\g
ulp-eslint\index.js:20:17)
    at Transform._transform (D:\Kolokvijumi\blur-admin-master\blur-admin-master\
node_modules\gulp-eslint\index.js:38:18)
    at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
```

I installed eslint, npm, babel-eslint but didnt help..

Comment: are you *sure* this is an **angularjs** theme?  this looks more like something you might encounter with **angular2**

Comment: that being said, which version of `eslint` are you using?  This appears to be something common with older releases of eslint.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1) since npm is kinda buggy, you should definitely try to wipe you node_modules folder and give an `npm cache clean` command. After that try reinstalling everything again with `npm install`

2) which version of Node are you using? There may be any compatibility issues with your current node version and the one needed by you modules. You should also have to try to use **nvm** to manage multiple node version on your system

--- EDIT (after the other answer) ---

Probably you need to (re)install [ESLint Config Defaults module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-defaults).